# Is it possible to model tables belonging to different databases in the same schema?

Tags: database, join, foreign-key-relationship, er-modeling

I need to build a system that in order to deliver the desired results to the user, queries (it uses a **join** operation) two tables each of them belonging to a **different database**. Therefore between them there is no physical relationship.

However, conceptually, there is a **one-to-many relationship** between them and I need to show this relationship in a ER model.

The modelling is an easy task, although I am not sure whether it is an approved practice to create a relationship between two tables which are not physically connected. If that is the case *"permitted"* is there any **graphical ER convention** to specify that the tables belong to different databases and that the relationship is just conceptual?

PS: the model I would like to design is used for both system documentation and to show the system structure to its stakeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible to **model**.

And apparently in many RDBMS it is not possible to implement without some (sometimes significant) drawbacks.

Comment: thanks for your answer! May you please list and motivate some of these drawbacks please?

Comment: 1. Not possible to get consistet backups without stopping write activity over databases

Comment: 2. If implemented with triggers - it adds overhead to every write operation